# apache httpd not start after install jk_module

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, mod-jk

I have WAMP server on window 7, I down load mod_jk.so(v 1.2.40 ) and place it on my modules folder and do following config on httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule jk_module>
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    emerg
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"

JkMount  /status  stat
JkMount  /*  balancer
</IfModule>
```

and add workers.properties with following :

```
worker.list=balancer,stat

worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost

worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.port=8010
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost

worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2

worker.stat.type=status
```

But when I try to start my apache server it no start.

How I fix this problem.
I also want to see error log, how i do this

Comment: I believe `jk_module` is to get Apache and `TOMCAT` to talk to each other. Have you installed the `tomcat server`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already installed two tomcat server and its also running

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by installing same version of Apache httpd and mod_jk lib.
but now balancer not work its show 500 error when I assess localhost/